# stop scrolling the page, scroll carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I have a problem with getting the effect. On the website I have carousels, I want to get - when I scroll the page and find a carousel, I want the carousel to start scrolling (scrolling the pages stopped), after discovering all the slides, I want the page to start scrolling.

```js
var slider = $('.slider');
$('.slider').slick({
  dots: false,
  vertical: true,
  arrows: false,
  variableWidth: false,
});

slider.on('wheel', (function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
    $(this).slick('slickPrev');
  } else {
    $(this).slick('slickNext');
  }
}));
```

```css
.slide {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>JS Bin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<section id="carousel">
  <div class=" position-relative">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide">
          <h1>Slide 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <h1>Slide 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <h1>Slide 3</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <h1>Slide 4</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

and [demo version](https://jsbin.com/medipuzano/edit?html,css,js,output)

How to solve this problem? to steal the page when the carousel is scrollable

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `edge` event isn't working. `beforeChange` will not fire when its the first or last slide, I've set `infinite` property to `true` and checking for last(or first) slide with `isLast`, have a look:

```js
var slider = $('.slider'),
  isLast = true,
  stop = false,
  next = 0;
$('.slider').slick({
  dots: false,
  vertical: true,
  arrows: false,
  variableWidth: false,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300
});

slider.on('wheel', (function(e) {
  if (!stop) {
    if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
      $(this).slick('slickPrev');
    } else {
      $(this).slick('slickNext');
    }

    if (!isLast) {
      event.preventDefault();
      isLast = true;
    } else {
      if (next != 0)
        stop = true;
    }
  }

}));

$('.slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  isLast = false;
  next = nextSlide;
});

$('.slider').on('edge', function(event, slick, direction) {
  console.log(slick, direction);
});
```

```css
.slide {
  background: green;
  height: 300px;
}

.container {
  margin: 300px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>JS Bin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<section id="carousel">
  <div class=" position-relative">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide">
          <h1>Slide 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <h1>Slide 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <h1>Slide 3</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <h1>Slide 4</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: but when scrolling does not stop the scroll on the carousel